# Retrieve custom post types by parent_id does not work (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to retrieve all the deals (custom post type) of a certain parent_id
This is the query:

```
$loop = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'deals', 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'posts_per_page' => -1]
```

And post defined as global $post; But if i am on the certain post page, it shows me all the deals, but i want only to see the deals with the parent_id=$post->ID. The deals (post type) are created as followed:

```
$data = [
        'post_parent'       => $postParent, // This one is hardcoded 749, the custom post ID of the one i choose.
        'post_type'         => 'deals',
        'post_title'        => $dealData['dealName'],
        'post_name'         => $dealData['dealName'],
        'post_status'       => 'publish',
        'comment_status'    => 'closed',
        'post_category'     => $dealData['country_category_id'],
    ];
```

Am i doing something wrong?